# Openstack Havana Installation

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

Hello I want to install openstack havana on my Single NIC machines. Will the installation work if i create virtual NIC's over single physical NIC

please reply with some references

Comment: I've done it with bridges.

Answer (score 0):

It does work as Matt pointed.

first create a bridge say br-proxy and add eth0 , eth1, eth2, eth3 to it.

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br-proxy
ovs-vsctl add-port br-proxy eth1
ovs-vsctl add-port br-proxy eth2
ovs-vsctl add-port br-proxy eth3
ovs-vsctl add-port br-proxy eth0
ip link set eth0 up promisc on
ip link set eth1 up promisc on
ip link set eth2 up promisc on
ip link set eth3 up promisc on
```

now proceed as a three nic device. Note that you will loose your ip connectivity after adding eth0 to br-proxy. To restore it assign the ip address of eth0 to br-proxy.

```
ifconfig br-proxy x.x.x.x/y up
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed openstack Havana on single NIC machine from using [this](https://github.com/mseknibilel/OpenStack-Grizzly-Install-Guide/blob/OVS_SingleNode/OpenStack_Grizzly_Install_Guide.rst) guide. Just changed following things

- changed the repository from grizzly to havana

`echo deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise-updates/havana main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/havana.list`

- Pointed all services to only single IP address.